# ionic 3 angular navigation from one page to another

Tags: angular, typescript, navigation, ionic3

i am building a website which means it has multiple pages. and a global navigation which u can click to go from one page to another.

For now say i have two pages:  Home, and Sales. From going home page to sales i did something like:

```
<ion-icon name="briefcase" style="zoom:3;color:#d31145" [navPush]="optyPage"></ion-icon>
<ion-label color="kelloggs" style="font-weight: bold">Sales</ion-label>
```

**and in .ts**

```
import { OpportunitiesPage } from '../opportunities/opportunities'

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  optyPage = OpportunitiesPage;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
}
```

Question is from opty page do i just do another navPush to go to home? or some other recommended way? also i don't know if i need to worry about clicking the home button while i am still on home (making to navpush calls)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `[navPop]`directive.

> Directive to declaratively pop the current page off from the
>   navigation stack.

```
<ion-content>

 <button ion-button navPop>Go Back</button>

</ion-content>
```

[**Oficial doc**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/nav/NavPop/)

Comment: well if i have button a and button b on both the pages. so how does it prevent the behavior if i hit button a while on page a. ?

Comment: It works only if it has a page on the page stack.Other wise it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Let's say you have  page 1, page 2 and page 3.  initially u r on page 1. now u go to page 3. and from page 3 u go to page 2.  now go to page 3 again. 

how will the flow now the difference between going from page 1 to page 3 vs going from page 2 to page 3? remember based on your explanation when u go to a page u do a navPush but when you are coming back u do a navPop.  so in my case it wont know if i m going first time or returning back?

Comment: You don't need to remember it.That is why we use the Ionic framework.It has been handled properly by the framework itself. In other words, Ionic handles the page routing properly. You can apply above on your web app and test it.

Comment: thanks buddy, i will try and mark the answer good or bad accordingly

Comment: Sure, Let us know about your findings :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to push Home back onto the nav stack again.  What you can simply do (and what I recommend) is add the following code to your opportunities.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Your Title</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Adding `ion-navbar` will give you a `Back` button in the header.  When the back button is clicked it does a navPop on the navStack and will take you back to your Home page.

Comment: it's a good solution for mobile apps but not on the website where there are many possible links that can be clicked to go to different pages. all the links are always visible as per the design requirement.

Comment: Ahh miss-read the question, apologies. I would suggest @Sampath solution then by adding a button that specifically does a `napPop`.